# Weird CSS Issue

Tags: html, css

On this site, the footer displays incorrectly in IE, and older version of FF, however displays perfectly in FF 3.6.13, any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

http://therhythmhut.com.au/

Comment: It might be because of `min-height` which might not be supported in all browsers, and really makes no sense.

Comment: So i'm not stupid after all, I couldn't see the problem myself :S

Answer (score 4):

IE7 doesn't support `display: table`, so your design is completely broken in IE7:

[image: broken in ie7]

I think you are better off just rewriting the footer so it doesn't use `display: table`, and your problem might fix itself.

I really like the design in Firefox and Chrome though!

Comment: I agree, the site looks pretty sweet. Good luck.